# Brand new JasperSoft Studio install has NoClassDefFoundErrors

Tags: noclassdeffounderror, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

**Is there something else I need to install or update to make this work?**

I downloaded and installed the latest version of both JasperReports products:

JasperSoft Server v 7.2.0
JasperSoft Studio v 6.9.0

I have set them up and can login to the Server from a web page.
When I try to create the "Server Connection" from Studio to the Server, it fails with this error.

```
NoClassDefFoundError: com/jaspersoft/studio/server/protocol/restv2/ClientQueryMapperProvider
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.restv2.RestV2ConnectionJersey.connect(RestV2ConnectionJersey.java:174)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.ProxyConnection.connect(ProxyConnection.java:102)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.WSClientHelper.checkConnection(WSClientHelper.java:92)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.wizard.ServerProfileWizard.connect(ServerProfileWizard.java:94)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.wizard.ServerProfileWizard.access$1(ServerProfileWizard.java:89)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.wizard.ServerProfileWizard$2.run(ServerProfileWizard.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Met with the same problem.
I had to install version 6.8.0 Jaspersoft Studio. There is no such problem

Comment: Yes, I did the same. I'm marking this as the answer because I am totally over it!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by selecting "Use SOAP protocol only" in the server connection setup.

[Jasper configure server connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGoVX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's caused by `hibernate` plugin. If you still want to use the `6.9.0` version, you can delete the `com.jaspersoft.studio.hibernate_5.4.1.final.jar` file from the plugins folder.